# R ggplot2 giving an odd graph, no idea why

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have tried to model the BTC supply and decided to use ggplot2 to graph it, I have tried to tinker with the code below that I wrote, however it gives me a graph which looks extraordinarily weird. Can someone pinpoint where I did something wrong?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
require(ggplot2)


start_btc=50
halvening_b=210000
time_prb=10
min_day=60*24
btcsupply=0
btcblockks=0
initial_date="2009-01-03"

start_time=0

period_ov=365*20

data_matrix_ts=matrix(nrow=period_ov,ncol=2)
colnames(data_matrix_ts) <- c("Date", "BTCSupply")

for (i in 1:period_ov){

  btcblocks=i*min_day/time_prb
  btcsupply=btcsupply+min_day/time_prb*start_btc/(2^(floor(btcblocks/halvening_b)))

  mat_date=as.Date(i,origin=initial_date)
  data_matrix_ts[i,1]=toString(mat_date)
  data_matrix_ts[i,2]=btcsupply
}

data_matrix_ts_df=as.data.frame(data_matrix_ts)

data_matrix_ts_df$Date <- as.Date( data_matrix_ts_df$Date, '%Y-%m-%d')
BSB_plot_1=ggplot(data = data_matrix_ts_df, aes( Date, BTCSupply, group=1 )) + geom_line()
```

Comment: your y variable is a factor. This is due to using a matrix to store your numbers - the date / string, and the numeric, however a matrix can only store one variable type, so coerces all variables to character. When you convert this to a dataframe it converts the character to a factor. Quick fix is `aes( Date, as.numeric(as.character(BTCSupply)), group=1)` , but really you should rewrite your code

Comment: What would you suggest instead of a maTRIX?

Comment: Yh you need the BTCSupply data to be numeric, not factor, you can easily make a `data.frame` with Date and vector of values...

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not quite sure I follow.

Comment: @nonein;first if you have multiple variable types like this you could store them in a list / dataframe structure. However, in this case there is no need for loops as your code can be easily vectorised. `btcblocks <- (1:period_ov)* min_day / time_prb ;  data_ts <- cumsum(min_day / time_prb* start_btc / (2^(floor(btcblocks / halvening_b)))) ;   mydate <- as.Date(1:period_ov, origin=initial_date) ;   data_matrix_ts_df2 <- data.frame(Date=mydate, BTCSupply=data_ts)`